# How to disable all the click events for a particular li item in all the files?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) bootstrap template.
I want to disable or turn off all the click event handlers attached to the sidebar item (expand/collapse behavior) on click of it.

Here is what I have tried so far but it only disables the current method.
Note: "do-not-open" is a particular class I have assigned to all the treeview li items.

```
    $(".do-not-open").on("click", function (e) {

    alert("Please select fields first");
/// $(this).unbind("click")
    $(this).off("click")

        return;

})
```

Now the .off() or .unbind() just disable the current click method and not the other event handlers in other files.
Here is the html of my code

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                <li class="active treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                        <span>Saved Queries</span>
                        <span class="label label-primary pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" id="saved-queries-options"></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview" id="new-query-tree">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span>Fields</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" id="field-options-list"></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview do-not-open">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                        <span>Conditions</span>
                    @*  <span class="label label-primary pull-right">0</span>*@
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li><button type="button" id="btn-add-new-condition" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm">Add New Condition</button></li>
                        <li class="disabled">
                            <div class="sidebar-form white">
                                <label>Selected Condition</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="condition-number"></select>
                                <label>Use: </label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="condition-pred" value="AND" class="flat-red" checked> AND
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="condition-pred" id="" value="OR" class="flat-red"> OR
                                </label>
                                <br />
                                <label>Select Table</label>
                                <select id="condition-table-options" class="form-control"></select>
                                <label>Select Field</label> <br />
                                <select class="form-control" id="condition-fields-options"></select>
                                <br />
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="condition-search-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Text">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <label>Use: </label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="condition-operator" value="equal" class="flat-red" checked> Equal
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="condition-operator" value="not-equal" class="flat-red"> Not Equal
                                </label>
                                <div class="icons">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" id="fast-back"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" id="back"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" id="forward"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" id="fast-forward"></span>




                                </div>
                                <select id="condition-filtered-list" size="6" class="form-control"></select>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview do-not-open">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                        <span>Production Forecast Options</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="years-check" id="Months" /> Months
                                </label>
                                <div class="years-input">
                                    <label>Start: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-start"></select>

                                    <label>End: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-end"></select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="years-check" id="Quarters" /> Quarters
                                </label>
                                <div class="years-input">
                                    <label>Start: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-start"></select>

                                    <label>End: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-end"> </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="years-check" id="Years" /> Years
                                </label>
                                <div class="years-input">
                                    <label>Start: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-start"> </select>

                                    <label>End: </label>
                                    <select class="form-control small years-end"> </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white">
                                <label>Fiscal Year Start Month: </label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="forecast-fy-month-start"> <option id=1 selected>January</option> <option id=2>February</option> <option id=3>March</option> <option id=4>April</option> <option id=5>May</option> <option id=6>June</option> <option id=7>July</option> <option id=8>August</option> <option id=9>September</option> <option id=10>October</option> <option id=11>November</option> <option id=12>December</option></select>


                                <label><input type="checkbox" id="fy-ends-calendar-year" /> Fiscal Year ENDS in Calendar Year </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="form-group white">
                                <label>Select Forecast: </label>
                                <select size="5" id="select-forecast-options" class="form-control"></select>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="form-group white">
                                <label>
                                    Select Currency
                                </label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="select-currency-options"> </select>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" id="grand-total-options" /> Include Grand Total </label>
                                <br />
                                <label>
                                    Show subtotal for:
                                </label>
                                <select size="6" class="form-control" id="show-subtotal-options"></select>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview do-not-open">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <span>Data Options</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"> Select Datapoint(s)</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white" id="data-points-options">

                            </div>
                            <a>Select Business Status(es)</a>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white" id="data-buisness-status-options">

                            </div>
                            <a>Select Part Type(s)</a>
                            <div class="sidebar-form white" id="part-type-options">

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview do-not-open">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Fields for Ordering</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu white" id="ordering-options"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the default behavior using [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)  API

```
$(".do-not-open").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ... Your codes here  
     return;

})
```

This will prevent redirection.

Comment: already tried that but it still it gets expanded after showing the alert

Comment: have you tried removing the css classes? it might something to with this classes. If you could provide the complete JS much better

Comment: No it is because of jQuery function slideUp in app.js of theme file.
How can I disable the call to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
$(".do-not-open").off('click');
```

which will remove the click for all matching `li` items?

Comment: I dont want to off for all of the li items. I just want to disable the particular one on which user clicks.

Comment: `$(this).off("click")` within the click handler that you have should disable all click handlers. You can also try `$(this).off()` if you want to remove all handlers for the `li` item that was clicked within the click handler.